# Two DCG rules for `(ab)*`. Can it be one?

Tags: prolog, dcg

I want to generate or test strings obeying the Perl Regex `(ab)*`

The code below works perfectly well:

**Generate**

```
?- phrase_acceptable(Text,6).
Text = abababababab ;
false.
```

**Test** (or compress?)

```
?- phrase_acceptable("ababab",N).
[97,98,97,98,97,98]
N = 3
```

**Enumerate possibilities**

```
?- phrase_acceptable(T,N).
T = '',
N = 0 ;
T = ab,
N = 1 ;
T = abab,
N = 2 ;
T = ababab,
N = 3 
...
```

However, this demands two clauses for `acceptable//1` which are selected based on whether `N` is fresh or not. Can that be avoided? Using CLP(FD) doesn't help, as one has to check that N>=0 in any case to avoid infinite descent.

```
ff(X) :- var(X).    % "freshvar(X)" using 2 letters, which is less annoying
bb(X) :- nonvar(X). % "notfreshvar(X)" using 2 letters, which is less annoying

acceptable(0) --> [].
acceptable(N) --> { bb(N), N>0, succ(Nm,N) }, `ab`, acceptable(Nm).  
acceptable(N) --> { ff(N) }, `ab`, acceptable(Nm), { succ(Nm,N) }. 

phrase_acceptable(Text,N) :-
   bb(Text),!,
   atom_codes(Text,Codes), 
   writeln(Codes),
   phrase(acceptable(N),Codes,[]).
   
phrase_acceptable(Text,N) :- 
   ff(Text),!,
   phrase(acceptable(N),Codes,[]),
   atom_codes(Text,Codes).
```

Comment: This is an age old question that I personally have been grappling with for years. While the case you present is simple and has a  nice solution as posted by @gusbro, when the DCG gets more complicated then the generator part typically needs constraints to limit the depth of the recursion. So this is a ominous warning to others that see this and try to expand on it and wonder why they are starting to go nuts. :) The solution I now take is to look at such problems as three different predicates. 1) recognizer 2) parser 3) generator.

Comment: @GuyCoder I fell this is related related to the predicates which work well in a "two-way relational manner" only for textbook problems and manicured built-ins. Once it gets messily complex, I feel the "two-way predicate" decays into two one-way predicates selected based on which parameter is fresh and for which the direction of the information flow between args is clear: ... the predicate is a shim hiding what is really two functions.  What Prolog needs: A syntax to make such selection explicit and make functional predicates explicit. It would probably help the compiler, too.

Comment: `What Prolog needs: A syntax to make such selection explicit and make functional predicates explicit.` That is worthy of thought. As I have noted in other places, my current view of Prolog is not a language to solve a problem but a language to create something, typically models or systems, and then use those to solve the problem. So while what you say has value I don't think it should be added directly to Prolog. However I also view Prolog has having some built-in models, e.g. DCG, Constraints, term rewriting, etc. Continued.

Comment: So I would view your idea as something that is a more extensive model for grammars that sits next to DCGs, e.g. [EDCG](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=edcg), or is something even more expressive but that it should not be viewed as part of the foundation of Prolog but a layer on top of Prolog or something along those lines of thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

acceptable(0) --> [].
acceptable(N1) -->  `ab`, { N #= N1-1, N #>= 0 }, acceptable(N).

phrase_acceptable(Text, N):-
  (nonvar(Text) -> atom_codes(Text, Codes) ; true),
  N #>= 0,
  phrase(acceptable(N), Codes, []),
  (var(Text) -> atom_codes(Text, Codes) ; true).
```

Test cases:

```
?- phrase_acceptable(ababab,N).
N = 3 ;
false.

?- phrase_acceptable(Text,3).
Text = ababab ;
false.

?- phrase_acceptable(Text,N).
Text = '',
N = 0 ;
Text = ab,
N = 1 ;
Text = abab,
N = 2 ;
Text = ababab,
N = 3 .
```